# How to show the full message rather than truncated one in Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, vim-go

I'm new to Vim. When I use Vim to write Go with vim-go plugin, I found it can mark the statements that go wrong. But what confuses me is that the message on the status bar(or command line?) is truncated and sometimes I couldn't see the whole message. I've tried `:messages` cmd, and tried to `:set cmdheight=5`, they just wouldn't work as I expected. Could anyone tell me how to show the full message?

[image: A gopls detection example]

Comment: Vim doesn't know about `gopls` and is not responsible for generating that "message" and there is no reason to expect the go-related plugin you use to use the built-in `:echomsg` to begin with. 1. See if that behaviour is described in the plugin's documentation, 2. try the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't find it in vim-go documention while I know another famous plugin ycm has something like 'show detailed diagnostic' that can do it.  Well I may try the issue tracker, thanks anyway.